# CMake set_property command with generator expressions using build type

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, hlsl

I'm creating a CMake project using v3.14.4 and the "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" generator.  During the build, a .hlsl file is also to be compiled and stored in the same directory as the .exe.  Something is preventing my generator for the hlsl file's `VS_SHADER_OBJECT_FILE_NAME` property from correctly being processed.

This is my CMake statement:

```
set_property(SOURCE shader.hlsl PROPERTY VS_SHADER_OBJECT_FILE_NAME
  $<$<CONFIG:Release>:Release/shader.dxbc>
  $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug/shader.dxbc>)
```

The result in VS shows the expression was pretty much passed through.

```
$<$<CONFIG:Release>:Release/shader.dxbc>;$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug/shader.dxbc>
```

I've used generators successfully with the `target_compile_definitions()` statement and `set_property()` is to also be supported.  Is my usage malformed or better written a different way?

Comment: Whether generator expressions are supported or not depends on the **property** (a name and a type). Since [documentation for the VS_SHADER_OBJECT_FILE_NAME property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/prop_sf/VS_SHADER_OBJECT_FILE_NAME.html) doesn't describe usage of generator expressions, one may assume that generator expressions are not supported for this property. Compare e.g. with [documentation for COMPILE_DEFINITIONS property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/prop_dir/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html), which supports generator expressions.

Comment: I see and will keep this in mind going forward.  For now I've added a custom command and it is getting the compiled shader to where I'd like it to be.

Comment: @PaulKippes If you found a solution to your problem, please post the solution as an *answer* to your question. Please do not embed the answer in the question post. This way, others with a similar problem can find the solution, and understand what fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Tsyvarev, the `VS_SHADER_OBJECT_FILE_NAME` property doesn't support generator expressions.  One solution to this is to copy the compiled shader to the desired destination for each build type, in this case the same directory as the .exe.  The below function `copy_compiled_shader` will copy `SHADERBC_FILE` to a new directory determined by using a generator function.

```
set_property(SOURCE shader.hlsl PROPERTY VS_SHADER_OBJECT_FILE_NAME shader.dxbc)

function(copy_compiled_shader SHADERBC_FILE)
  add_custom_command(
    TARGET TestCS
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Copying the shader ${SHADERBC_FILE}"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${SHADERBC_FILE} $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:TestCS>/${SHADERBC_FILE}
  )
endfunction()

copy_compiled_shader(shader.dxbc)
```